# Can I create a docker in Google Colab?

Tags: python, pytorch, google-colaboratory

I want to create a version of my Colab notebook that will be immune to changes in the standardly used versions of python and pytorch within colab. Essentially creating something like a docker that will not need to be updated. Is this possible?

Ideally I'd like to keep them as:

Python version: 3.7
PyTorch version: 1.10.0+cu111
CUDA version: 11.1
cuDNN version: 8005

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about Google Colab, but in general, you can achieve this by "pin" versions of:

- docker image you built and always go off your custom docker image (meaning any changes to python and packages versions won't affect already built image) [link](https://nickjanetakis.com/blog/docker-tip-18-please-pin-your-docker-image-versions)
- pin your packages inside Dockerfile so rebuilds ALWAYS use the same version

This could solve your use-case

Comment: Thanks so much for the response. It's not actually possible to run Docker in Colab (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62238690/running-docker-on-google-colab), but I want something to keep the environment identical each time I load up my Colab Notebook