# Persistent Data With Colab on GCE VM

Tags: google-colaboratory, google-compute-engine

I have recently connected my Colab notebook to a custom GCE VM since the idea behind using a custom VM is to have dedicated resources, right? However, I do not understand why isn't there any way to mount VM's local directories to the Colab docker container so that we can have persistent data.

I can see two mounts:

```
"Mounts": [
    {
        "Type": "bind",
        "Source": "/tmp/colab-shared",
        "Destination": "/var/colab/shared",
        "Mode": "",
        "RW": true,
        "Propagation": "rprivate"
    },
    {
        "Type": "bind",
        "Source": "/tmp/var-colab",
        "Destination": "/var/colab",
        "Mode": "",
        "RW": true,
        "Propagation": "rprivate"
    }
],
```

Is there any workaround? I was using Google Drive, and it is very slow.

Comment: Check these similar [SO1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62238690/running-docker-on-google-colab) for Alternative & [SO2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49360888/google-colab-is-very-slow-compared-to-my-pc) for speed up.