# How to run docker on google colab

Tags: docker, google-colaboratory

I tried installing docker on google colab using the following commands I found [in another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62238690/running-docker-on-google-colab):

```
%%shell     

sudo apt update -qq

sudo apt install apt-transport-https ca-certificates curl software-properties-common -qq

curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo apt-key add -

sudo add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic stable" -y

sudo apt update -qq -y

sudo apt install docker-ce -y

docker
```

Then I try confirming docker works with the following:

```
!docker --version
!docker info
!docker run hello-world
```

Which gives the following info and error:

```
Docker version 24.0.2, build cb74dfc
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:    24.0.2
 Context:    default
 Debug Mode: false
 Plugins:
  buildx: Docker Buildx (Docker Inc.)
    Version:  v0.10.5
    Path:     /usr/libexec/docker/cli-plugins/docker-buildx
  compose: Docker Compose (Docker Inc.)
    Version:  v2.18.1
    Path:     /usr/libexec/docker/cli-plugins/docker-compose

Server:
ERROR: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
errors pretty printing info
docker: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

Then I've tried various command to start the docker daemon, such as `!sudo systemctl start docker` which gave the output

```
docker: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?. See 'docker run --help'. System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate. Failed to connect to bus: Host is down
```

Comment: And what the `systemctl start docker` cmd shows you?

Comment: Edited question with what systemctl start docker shows